# Is there any mechanism in cassandra that sends notification when table is changed through INSERT or UPDATE query?

Tags: java, cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and I would like to know does cassandra support any mechanism which will send notification when some table is changed through INSERT/UPDATE query and any mechanism like cursor to iterate through results.

Answer (score 4):

`Cassandra Triggers` will help you. Refer [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/trigger_r.html) and [this](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-0-prototype-triggers-support). Also I found an example in [Github](https://github.com/markreddy/cassandra-trigger-example)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! But Cassandra Triggers are used to execute some procedural code on table modification. Actually i just need a notification to be sent from cassandra when INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations is performed on a particular table. Can you help me in this regard.

Comment: What do you exactly mean `notification?` From your comment, `Actually i just need a notification to be sent from cassandra` It is your business requirement, cassandra will not give your business requirement. Trigger will be executed if you do any modification at the table level( Insert / Delete, Update). Your business requirement notification, that you need to implement in the trigger level.